# Writing decimal numbers in english

Tags: notation

When we write decimal numbers in Persian language (with Persian digits) we usually use "/" instead of "." for example $123/12$ means $123.12$ but I am writing numbers in English Should I write it $123.12$ ? and $123/12$ means $123$ divide by $12$ in this context?

Comment: Depends on your audience. If your audience does math in english, pick ".', otherwise pick "/"

Comment: @DonThousand in English do you use "/" for decimal numbers?

Comment: Yes, in English $123.12 = 123 + \frac{12}{100}$ and $123/12 = 123 \div 12$

Comment: In German, we use comma as decimal separator (so $123{,}12$ - which should not be confused with $123,12$). In an English text, all English "locale" settings should be used, so even I as a German would write $123.12$ when writing English. Even if you write Persian *text*, but with numbers in English, I'd suggest to use the English decimal point instead of adding another layer of confusion

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thank you for the answer.

Comment: In Italian we write $123,12$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This should be an official answer.

Comment: Wikipedia has what appears to be a pretty [comprehensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Hindu-Arabic_numerals) of countries using the comma, the period, and other symbols as decimal separator. Most of Continental Europe, South America, and northern Asia use the comma, along with a sizeable chunk of Africa.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott this is interesting information. by the way do you suggest me to use dot as the decimal separator  when I am writing digits in English?

Comment: @philomath: Yes, definitely.